# Xcode was able to build C program but run/test/profile options are disabled

Tags: xcode

I added a new C project with *external build system* setting since I got the source from an open source project.  I copied all the source code into the project folder and added them into Xcode.  I was able to build successfully using `/usr/bin/make` directly in the project folder.

However, the Run/Test/Profile menu options are disabled and I'm unable to run the program...

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by manually putting all C source files into a new target rather than using the external Makefile.